# where can I get the default cylinder start position to create new partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, fdisk

So I have two partitions, I deleted the 2nd one, then want to re-create it. My work is to automate this process. 
But after I deleted the 2nd partition the default suggested start cylinder from fdisk is 1. If I type enter then fdisk will create a tiny partition from 1 to 50. 
But if I type 500 then it will give me a new default value suggestion about 1050 which is behind the 1st partition.

How can I get this default cylinder value behind the 1st partition?

Comment: So type 500 and accept the default 1050 as you state. Or, is the issue that you have not explained the problem clearly?

Comment: @SolarMike yes. you are right, to automate this process this action is sufficient. But I am still wondering where I can get this value. Cause in sys/block/sdb/sdb2 I cannot find anything related with cylinder.